# Update a column in SQL, inserting a character at a specific point

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a SQL table gathering form results. I noticed after about 200 results had been gathered, that instead of the date being in the format of 2011-06-01, that it was in the format of 2011-6-01, skipping the leading zero. This is giving some data processing problems. Is there a way to update all the 2011-6-xx values to make then 2011-06-xx? Solutions in either PHP/MySQL or just MS-SQL statements are acceptable, as the data is collected on a webserver using a PHP/MySQL form, exported to CSV, and then imported into an MS-SQL database on site for data analysis.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date_column` = REPLACE(`date_column`, '2011-6-', '2011-06-') WHERE `date_column` LIKE '2011-6-%';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET field1 = REPLACE(field1, '2011-6-', '2011-06-')
WHERE field1 LIKE '2011-6%'
```

The where will allow you to use an index and replace much faster than looking through all rows.
Also in `strict` mode MySQL will not execute UPDATE statements without a `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You talk about MS-SQL and MySQL. If it's MS SQL, then the below should work. I don't know if MySQL uses `REPLACE` or has an equivalent function.

```
UPDATE
    Some_Table
SET
    some_string = REPLACE(some_string, '2011-6-', '2011-06-')
WHERE
    some_string LIKE '2011-6%'
```

Comment: MySQL can use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT` to do a "update, if not exists insert" kind of operation, this is **not** recommended for general updates though, because it deletes a row and then recreates it, breaking auto_incrementing primary keys. BTW UPDATE is standard SQL, every dialect supports it.

Comment: It sounds like the MySQL `REPLACE` is not at all like the string function `REPLACE` in MS SQL then, which was more my point. I'm vaguely familiar with ANSI SQL ;)

Comment: Sorry for being a silly cow `:-0`, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace for details on the `string` function replace.